# Office 365 Unified Api (preview )

Tags: office365

I tried to implement O365 unified api(beta version). 
I got successfully all groups. 
I faced problem to get files of a particular group.
It gives UnAuthorized (401) Error. when I checked in fiddler it returns an error from server in webview. If anyone knows how to fix please help me.

Thanks
Rajinder

Comment: any code to show us?

Answer (score 0):

Rajinder, this is a permission issue. During the preview, to get access to group files you need to select the permission "read all site collections". We will fix this for GA, where the only scope required will be "read all groups"

Comment: I have already given permissions (read all site collections
, All groups, all files) still file access is not working.

Comment: Please send us the request-id for investigation, is a header in the response.