# Office365 unified APIs group files returns 404 Unable to provision resource

Tags: rest, office365

Although it was working and I didn't modify anything in this module, Office365 unified rest APIs for getting group files gives the following 404 with error Unable to provision resource.

Comment: Hey, Alaa. Can you provide more details for me please? Like a copy of your request would be awesome. Thank you!

Comment: So I tried this request myself and am running into the same issue as you. Looks like this question was already asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32378526/office-365-unified-api-preview), but left unresolved. My suggestion right now is to try the suggestion in the other thread, which is adding the permission "Read items in all site collections". Let me know if that works for you, otherwise, I'll look for a better answer.

Comment: thank you @JoeMartella for your response, my application already have  "Read items in all site collections" permission.

Comment: Looks like an internal failure that we would need a request id to investigate

Comment: @Yine 
Request id: 193fe185-8acd-40d4-850b-d6f00f1498e1 
I know you will get the request details, but here is a fast way to see it:
https://www.getpostman.com/collections/3be942bde1ff8fe9e9d6

Comment: Thank you, after investigation it is actually lack of the "Read and write items in all site collections" permission scope. Again this is a preview limitation and we are working on fixing it soon.